# Add a rule blocking the IP address through the API Windows Firewall Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, firewall

Good afternoon. 
Nobody faced with the addition of a Windows Firewall rules in Delphi? 
I need to restrict incoming and outgoing connections from specific IP addresses. 
This code throws me an application at startup with an error:

> Exception EVariantInvalidOpError in module Project1.exe at 00033E74. Invalid variant operation.

Does anyone have what error?

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Const
 NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP = 6;
 NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP = 17;
 NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW = 1;
 NET_FW_RULE_DIR_in = 1;

var
 CurrentProfiles : OleVariant;
 fwPolicy2       : OleVariant;
 RulesObject     : OleVariant;
 NewRule         : OleVariant;
 txtAddress      : OleVariant;
 NET_FW_ACTION_  : OleVariant;
 NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_: OleVariant;

begin
  // Create the FwPolicy2 object.
  fwPolicy2   := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
  RulesObject := fwPolicy2.Rules;
  CurrentProfiles := fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;
   txtaddress.text:='192.168.1.33';
  //Create a Rule Object.
  NewRule := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FWRule');

        newrule.Name:= 'BrutalNT: IP Access Block ' + txtAddress.Text;
        newrule.Description := 'Block Incoming Connections from IP Address.';
        newrule.Action := 1;
        newrule.Direction := NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN;
        newrule.Enabled := true;
        newrule.InterfaceTypes := 'All';
        newrule.RemoteAddresses := txtAddress.Text;

  //Add a new rule
  RulesObject.Add(NewRule);
end;
```

Comment: Are you running your application with elevated privilegies? As far as I know any program which wants to change Windows Firewall settings must be run with administrative privilegies.

Comment: The address doesn't give us the line number. Step through the code in the debugger and tell us the line which raises the exception.

Comment: [Using the Windows Firewall with Advanced Security scripting API and Delphi](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2013/11/21/using-the-windows-firewall-with-advanced-security-scripting-api-and-delphi/)

Comment: As side note: you'll get much cleaner code if you drop late binding approach and import type library.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `txtAddress : OleVariant` but without any structure behind. So you cannot use something like `txtAddress.text`, because there is nothing where this can be mapped.

Simply change the type to `string`, there is no need for `txtAddress` to be of type `OleVariant`.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
Const
 NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_TCP = 6;
 NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_UDP = 17;
 NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK = 0;
 NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW = 1;
 NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN = 1;

var
 CurrentProfiles : OleVariant;
 fwPolicy2       : OleVariant;
 RulesObject     : OleVariant;
 NewRule         : OleVariant;
 txtAddress      : string; // OleVariant;

begin
  // Create the FwPolicy2 object.
  fwPolicy2   := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FwPolicy2');
  RulesObject := fwPolicy2.Rules;
  CurrentProfiles := fwPolicy2.CurrentProfileTypes;
  txtaddress{.text}:='192.168.1.33';
  //Create a Rule Object.
  NewRule := CreateOleObject('HNetCfg.FWRule');

  Newrule.Name := 'BrutalNT: IP Access Block ' + txtAddress{.Text};
  Newrule.Description := 'Block Incoming Connections from IP Address.';
  Newrule.Action := NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK{1};
  Newrule.Direction := NET_FW_RULE_DIR_IN;
  Newrule.Enabled := true;
  Newrule.InterfaceTypes := 'All';
  Newrule.RemoteAddresses := txtAddress{.Text};

  //Add a new rule
  RulesObject.Add(NewRule);
end;
```

**BTW** If you want to **block** you have to set `NewRule.Action := 0;` (NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK)